# VB - Find child form from parent

Tags: vb.net, forms

I am in a project with multiple form.

I create a TicTacToe form here :

```
 Private Sub MenuTicTacToe(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim page As Form = New TicTacToe
    page.Show(Me)
End Sub
```

Here is a TicTacToe form:

```
Public Class TicTacToe

    Public opponent as String
    'Some code where user set opponent

    Public Function Receive(S As String)
    if string = opponent
        'Some code
    End Function

End Class
```

I would like to call my function Receive in my main form
If i do:

TicTactoe.Receive(S)
It call a instance of Receive where opponent does not exist.

I would like to find the oppened form of TicTacToe and call Receive

Thanks

Comment: can you be more specific in your question please? it is hard to tell exactly what you want. Thx

Comment: I improved the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this to show the form

```
Dim page As TicTacToe
Private Sub MenuTicTacToe(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    page = New TicTacToe
    page.Show(Me)
End Sub
```

Then you can use

```
page.Receive(S)
```

**Edit**

To  use multiple forms

```
For Each f As TicTacToe in Application.OpenForms().OfType(Of TicTacToe)
        f.Receive (S)
Next
```

Comment: Thanks
It works for 1 form at least.

But if i call twice MenuTicTacToe and create 2 form, the function dont seems to be called in the 2 forms

Comment: That's perfect now. Thanks

Comment: Actually it dont works. When i call my forms, the same form (the last one) is called twice and the other zero

Comment: Then you may have to create different forms and copy the contents of your Tictactoe form to them then you can refer to them by their individual names.

Comment: i'm not sure. The purpose is to create an Online TicTacToe, and allow user to lauch as many game they want. Then when i receive a hit, i must check all games forms if the opponent name is the one of the hit received. So the answer you gave looks like it. Because if i create differents form, i will have a limited number of play, right ?

Comment: Oups sry actually it works, that was an other error in the earlier code that make it disfunction. Thank you very much for your answers

Comment: @Phoenix It's not very good practice on SO to change what you are asking in a comment, and then accepting a different answer *based on that comment*. Just saying.

Answer (score 1):

Comments in line

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    page.Receive("Joe")
End Sub
'A form level variable to hold a reference to the instance of TicTacToe
'Although vb.net can use default instances, you have created an explicit
'instance of TicTacToe so you need to keep a reference if you want to
'refer to this instance.
Private page As TicTacToe
Private Sub MenuTicTacToe(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    page = New TicTacToe()
    page.Show(Me)
End Sub

Partial Public Class TicTacToe
    Inherits Form
    Public opponent As String
    'Functions must be declared as a Type
    'If you do not need a return value use a Sub
    Public Function Receive(S As String) As String
        Dim someString As String = ""
        If S = opponent Then
            'Do something
        End If
        'There must be a return Value
        Return someString
    End Function

End Class
```

Comment: The OP's not looking for a  tutorial on how to use functions! :)

Comment: @preciousbetine  When I see incorrect code in a question I try to correct it and add an explanation. I am sorry if this bothers you.

Answer (score 0):

In C#, you'd need a new instance, but as you are in VB, the compiler already does that for you.

What you are currently doing, is creating a new instance of the `TicTacToe` form and showing it:

```
Private Sub MenuTicTacToe(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim page As Form = New TicTacToe
    page.Show(Me)
End Sub
```

But you don't save that instance anywhere. Then, in your next piece of code, you are using a different instance, which is the static one created by the compiler:

```
TicTacToe.Receive(S) // TicTacToe is the static instance
```

Therefore, you end up calling two different instances, which explains why there is no opponent set.

To get around this problem, do not create a new instance. In your `Private Sub MenuTicTacToe`, just use the instance created by the compiler, and you won't have this problem, just like this:

```
Private Sub MenuTicTacToe(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    TicTacToe.Show(Me)
End Sub
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks then It works for 1 form. But if i call twice MenuTicTacToe and create 2 form (or then more), how to call the function in every form ?

Comment: @Phoenix Which function do you want to call? If you want to call the Receive method, just use it like above. If I understand you correctly, you can just use above code again and replace the form names, just don't create form instances yourself. Oh and btw, if an answer solved your problem, you can mark it as "accepted" using the green check mark below the vote buttons, so that it disappears from the "unanwered" section.

Comment: i want to call receive but in several forms. @preciousbetine answer looks like what i want to do, but something dont work